# Stuttering when opening several tabs on high end PC

Tags: audio, performance, bluetooth

I have a pretty good PC. Specs:

- [Intel Core i7-6700K Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/88195/Intel-Core-i7-6700K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz)
- [Nvidia 980 TI](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-980-ti) video card
- 16 GB DDR4 RAM
- SSD with plenty of space
- good motherboard ([MSI Z170A Gaming M5](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/Z170A-GAMING-M5.html#hero-specification))
- OS: Windows 10, latest updates, multiple restarts.

I also have a Bluetooth headset connected to the PC but the problem appears even when I remove it from Devices.

When I open a tab in Google Chrome or IE, the computer starts extreme stuttering. I can move control it using the mouse but cursor is very laggy. If audio is playing either from browser or a file, it stutters too. After a few seconds, when tab is loaded fully, stuttering goes away. If I open several tabs at once, stuttering gets worse or/and longer.

When I observe CPU, Memory and Disk in Task Manager, I see a spike in CPU usage while Memory stays the same. However, CPU does not go above 60%. Ethernet is also spiking.

I've had this problem for a while but I ignored it, and just waited until web page is loaded fully but it got too annoying.

Now, what do you think could be the problem?

Comment: You say you have a good motherboard, but fail to advise which one.  What ethernet chipset does it have ?   I'm wondering if it has a Realtek chipset and this is causing issues ?

Comment: Chipset is Killer E2400, MSI 7977.

Comment: If it's the wrong mainboard please correct it. If you're seeing 60% CPU load that would mean two (physical) cores are maxed out. Are you doing anything besides it? How many tabs do you have open?